# What's the issue with my onClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, onclick, onclicklistener

I am trying to write a simple app that displays a coloured circle which fades to black as it gets further from the centre of the screen. However, whenever I click the app, it crashes. When I remove the onClick code the app runs fine. The only error I can find in logcat is:

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x94 in tid 11955 (raphicstutorial)

And I don't know what to do with that.

Code below:

```
package com.example.a2dgraphicstutorial;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public class MyView extends View {
    private Canvas thisCanvas;
    private int colourID;
    private Paint fillPaint = new Paint();

    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
        colourID = 0;
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    public void drawCircle(){
        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();

        //Drawing the circles
        for (int i = 255;i >= 0;i--){
            //Determining colour
            if (colourID == 0){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,255-i,0,0));
            }
            else if (colourID == 1){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,255-i,0));
            }
            else if (colourID == 2){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255-i));
            }

            thisCanvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,i,fillPaint);
        }

        //Cycling the colourID so the next circle will be a different colour
        colourID = (colourID + 1)%3;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        thisCanvas = canvas;

        //Setting the background to be black
        fillPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        thisCanvas.drawPaint(fillPaint);

        //Drawing the first circle
        drawCircle();
    }

}
MyView theScreen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    theScreen = new MyView(this);
    theScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            theScreen.drawCircle();
        }
    });

    setContentView(theScreen);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding the `onCreate()`

**Override `onTouchEvent()` and listen to a click:**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            //the finger is down do something.....

            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //the finger is up do something.....(this is a click)
            //to redraw
            invalidate();

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**By the way:**

To trigger the `onDraw()`, call this after a click:

```
invalidate();
```

Comment: Having implemented this, the original issue persists. Perhaps it isn't to do with the onClick method at all?

Comment: remove the onCreate() method you don't need it, just keep the method I told you to use.

Comment: I still need to declare theScreen, which requires that method, doesn't it?

Comment: Just implement what I told you it will help you listen to the finger when it performs a click on the screen, after the `ACTION_UP` you can call `invalidate()` to redraw again.

Comment: Yes, I did, and as I have already said, the original issue persists. I cannot remove the onCreate() method, so we're back to square one.

Comment: Why you can't remove onCreate() what is the use of it in your view.

Comment: Because theScreen is declared there, and syntax errors occur if it is declared elsewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213503/discussion-between-xerxes-and-hasan-bou-taam).

Answer (score 0):

One upon a time I had a problem similar to this
and the solutions was to replace "this" by "the name of activity".class

```
// replace this to theScreen = new MyView(this);
       theScreen = new MyView(MainActivity.class);
```

Another solution is to replace this By "**getBaseContext()**"

```
// replace this to theScreen = new MyView(this);
           theScreen = new MyView(getBaseContext());
```

1. ***this*** the context returns the current context of the activity, belong to the activity, the activity is destroyed then it will destroy also.
2. ***getBaseContext()*** is the method of ContextWrapper Which is "Proxying implementation of Context that simply delegates all of its calls to another Context. Can be subclassed to modify behaviour
   without changing the original Context."

Comment: Replacing "this" with "MainActivity.class" results in a syntax error; replacing "this" with "getBaseContext()" seems to make no difference to how the code runs.

Comment: Because you should replace "    setContentView(theScreen);" to setContentView(R.layout.main)

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when you call the Canvas outside of the onDraw method, try this code

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public class MyView extends View {
        private Canvas thisCanvas;
        private int colourID;
        private Paint fillPaint = new Paint();

    public MyView(Context context){
        super(context);
        colourID = 0;
        fillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        thisCanvas = canvas;

        //Setting the background to be black
        fillPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
        thisCanvas.drawPaint(fillPaint);

        int x = getWidth();
        int y = getHeight();

        //Drawing the circles
        for (int i = 255;i >= 0;i--){
            //Determining colour
            if (colourID == 0){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,255-i,0,0));
            }
            else if (colourID == 1){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,255-i,0));
            }
            else if (colourID == 2){
                fillPaint.setColor(Color.argb(255,0,0,255-i));
            }

            thisCanvas.drawCircle(x/2,y/2,i,fillPaint);
        }

        //Cycling the colourID so the next circle will be a different colour
        colourID = (colourID + 1)%3;
    }

}
MyView theScreen;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    theScreen = new MyView(this);
    theScreen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            theScreen.invalidate();
        }
    });
    setContentView(theScreen);
}

}
```

I moved the `drawCircle` method to inside the `onDraw` and change `theScreen` from calling `drawCircle` to call `invalidate()` instead, I'm not sure it's the result you want but at least that's the issue of the error.